# Multer не сохраняет файлы

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

Вот код роутера с multer -

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const config = require('config');
const cors = require('cors');
const { stat } = require('fs');

const router = express();

const corsOptions = {
    origin: config.get('CORS.white'),
    optionsSuccessStatus: config.get('CORS.optionsSuccessStatus')
}

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'picture_db');
    },
    filename(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024
    },
    fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
        const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        if (ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.jpeg' && ext !== '.png') {
            const err = new Error('Extention');
            err.code = 'EXTENTION';
            return cb(err);
        }
        cb(null, true);
    }
}).single('file')

router.post('/image',
    cors(corsOptions),
    async(req, res) => {
        try {
            const reqBody = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));

            let status;

            upload(req, res, err => {
                let error = '';

                if (err) {
                    if (err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE') {
                        error = 'Размер изображения не должен превышать 2мб';
                    }
                    if (err.code === 'EXTENTION') {
                        error = 'Файл не является ни jpg, ни jpeg, ни png';
                    }
                    status = error;
                }
            });

            return res.status(200).json({
                msg: status || 'OK',
            });
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                msg: "a"
            });
        }
    }
);

module.exports = router;
```

В корне проекта есть папка `picture_db`.

При попытке отправить запрос на загрузку файла -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке загрузить картинку, она не сохраняется в `picture_db`. Почему?

Comment: а ты так и не понял ничего про асинхронность, колбэки и т.п.?

Comment: в общем, скорее всего нужно выправить указание на каталог, что-то вроде `cb(null, path.join(process.cwd(), 'picture_db'));`. и ошибку в консоль вывести. потому что ошибка произойдёт после того как клиент получит ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что при вызове метода `single` у `multer()` определяется ключ, по которому из запроса можно получить файл, сама ошибка была в запросе, который по правильному должен был выглядеть так:

```json
{
  "file": {filename}
}
```